# Numpy loadtxt works with urllib2 response but not requests response

Tags: python, csv, numpy, python-requests, urllib2

I am attempting to load a csv file from a url such as http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=PXD&d=9&e=17&f=2015&g=d&a=11&b=12&c=1970&ignore=.csv into a numpy array using loadtxt. If I use urllib2.urlopen(url) this works fine but I am running into errors with requests.get(url)

Example:

```
file = urllib2.urlopen(url)
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,AdjClose = np.loadtxt(file, unpack=True, delimiter=',', skiprows=1,converters={0:mdates.strpdate2num('%Y-%m-%d')})
print AdjClose[:5]
```

Returns:

```
[ 140.570007  136.580002  133.240005  131.889999]
```

However doing the same with:

```
file = requests.get(url)
```

Results in errors such as this no matter what changes I have been attempting to make to the parameters:

```
ValueError: time data '33.00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'
```

Adding .text to requests.get(url) results in one long string of the entire data set along with \n characters.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `requests`, I think you need to explicitly iterate over the lines of the response, otherwise `loadtxt` won't pick up the individual rows properly. Try:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,AdjClose = np.loadtxt(file.iter_lines(),
            unpack=True, delimiter=',', skiprows=1,
            converters={0:mdates.strpdate2num('%Y-%m-%d')})
```